# Pyqt Add the same widget object in different layouts

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I now want to use Pyqt to design such a set of logic, add two different widget in two layouts, these two different widget use the same widget, because I want to share the data of the same widget in different layouts But unfortunately my design failed, in the case, I can't show two PYQT on the display,can anyone help me

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Series(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Series, self).__init__()
        self.lb = QLabel('PYQT')


class SeriesHBox1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super(SeriesHBox1, self).__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(series.lb)


class SeriesHBox2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super(SeriesHBox2, self).__init__()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.hbox.addWidget(series.lb)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 300)
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        box1 = QHBoxLayout()
        box2 = QHBoxLayout()
        box.addLayout(box1)
        box.addLayout(box2)

        series = Series()
        box1.addWidget(SeriesHBox1(series))
        box2.addWidget(SeriesHBox2(series))
        # box2.addWidget(SeriesHBox2(Series()))

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: A widget cannot be in two different parents. A way to share your data would be to use the MVC design pattern for `series`

Comment: Who are their parents here

Comment: When you call `addWidget`, you implicitly set the parent of `series` to `box1` then `box2`

Comment: I used your ideas to modify my code, but I did not succeed. I am not sure whether the modification is correct. Do you have simple code?

Comment: Hello i modified my code and this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widget cannot be in two different widgets at the same time. So, you have to create two `Series` instances (one for each `SeriesHBox`).

The simpliest way to share the data (let's say the content of your label) is to extract the state (the text) in another object that will be shared by the `Series` instance and will update them when the content has changed.

A quick example :

```
class SeriesModel(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SeriesModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._content = "PYQT"

    contentChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    @pyqtProperty(str, notify=contentChanged)
    def content(self):
        return self._content

    @content.setter
    def content(self, value):
        self._content = value

class Series(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(Series, self).__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.lb = QLabel(model.content)

        self.model.contentChanged.connect(self.lb.setText)



class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 300)
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        box1 = QHBoxLayout()
        box2 = QHBoxLayout()
        box.addLayout(box1)
        box.addLayout(box2)


        model = SeriesModel(self)

        series1 = Series(model)
        series2 = Series(model)

        box1.addWidget(SeriesHBox1(series1))
        box2.addWidget(SeriesHBox2(series2))

        self.show()
```

If you change the content in `SeriesModel` the two labels will be updated, also.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is great

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have PyQt5.
Create two instances of the `Series` class

```
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *
#from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import random


class Series(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Series, self).__init__()
        self.lb = QLabel('PYQT')
        self.lb.setStyleSheet("""background-color: {};""".format(
            QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)).name()
        )
    )


class SeriesHBox1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super(SeriesHBox1, self).__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(series.lb)


class SeriesHBox2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super(SeriesHBox2, self).__init__()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.hbox.addWidget(series.lb)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 300)
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        box1 = QHBoxLayout()
        box2 = QHBoxLayout()
        box.addLayout(box1)
        box.addLayout(box2)

#        series = Series()
        series1 = Series()                                # +
        series2 = Series()                                # +

        box1.addWidget(SeriesHBox1(series1))
        box2.addWidget(SeriesHBox2(series2))
        # box2.addWidget(SeriesHBox2(Series()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the answer I want, I hope there is only one series object, but still appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer i want

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


class Series(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Series, self).__init__(parent)
        self.lb = QLabel('PYQT')


class SeriesHBox1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super(SeriesHBox1, self).__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.addWidget(series.lb)


class SeriesHBox2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, series):
        super(SeriesHBox2, self).__init__()
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.hbox.addWidget(series.lb)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 300)
        box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(box)

        box1 = QHBoxLayout()
        box2 = QHBoxLayout()
        box.addLayout(box1)
        box.addLayout(box2)
        s = Series()
        h = SeriesHBox1(s)
        s.__init__(h)
        print(s)
        box1.addWidget(h)
        b = SeriesHBox2(s)
        s.__init__(b)
        print(s)
        box2.addWidget(b)

        c = QPushButton()
        c.clicked.connect(self.close_a)

        d = QPushButton()
        d.clicked.connect(self.close_b)

        box.addWidget(c)
        box.addWidget(d)
        self.show()

    def close_a(self):
        self.a.hide()

    def close_b(self):
        self.b.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```